# Deploy Spring boot and angular project to weblogic 12c

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a spring-boot application with angular as the frontend on weblogic 12c (12.2.1). My code is available at - https://github.com/onkar0777/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT

I have created a war with mvn clean install and it runs fine on running with java -jar

But when I deploy the same war to weblogic, on hitting http://192.168.1.6:7001/myweb I get the error (myweb is context-root)

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Aug 22 13:28:58 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Forbidden, status=403). Access Denied

I am guessing somehow weblogic is not directing calls to the MainController

```
package com.app.api;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import springfox.documentation.annotations.*;

@ApiIgnore
@Controller // Dont use RestController as this method is mapping to a static file not a JSON
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping(value={"/"})
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.app;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

import com.app.services.StorageService;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={ "com.app.repo"})
@EntityScan(basePackages ={ "com.app.model"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner, WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Resource
    StorageService storageService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg) throws Exception {
        storageService.deleteAll();
        storageService.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MainApp.class).bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    }

}
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>/myweb</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this (updating here after a delay). So it turned out to be a combination of a few stupid things on my part.
For anyone struggling with deploying apps with angular frontend on weblogic, code is same as I posted in the question and all updates are available on the [repo](https://github.com/onkar0777/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT)

The important things which need to be kept in mind are:

- In weblogic you need to explicitly go to the index.html file for the UI to get started, so I needed to go this exact url - http://192.168.1.6:7001/myweb/index.html
- The base url is now myweb so had to introduce corresponding changes through environment files
- For deployment on weblogic you need to build angular app with base-href option:

> ng build --prod --env=prod --base-href=/myweb/

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your weblogic.xml file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:container-descriptor>

<!-- <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>-->
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:package-name>net.minidev.json.*</wls:package-name> 
<wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>javax.websocket.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>javax.websocket.server.*</wls:package-name>
<wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng build --base-href /myweb --deploy-url /myweb/   for angular 15 I had to specify deploy-url also